# Load More button "per_page" giving error

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

Im trying to make a `load more` button that will load 4 items at a time. Im using `will_paginate` and `kaminari`.  Im getting an error with this current code:

**1)** I get this error when loading the page and having the `per_page` part in the controller object.: 
`undefined method 'to_model' for 2:Fixnum`

- I just need to figure out how to add the number of items per page then i can continue with the js.

```html
<%= link_to 'show_more', @reservations_completed.next_page, :remote => true, :id => 'show_more_link' %>
```

```rails
@reservations_completed = current_user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 4)
```

---

**2)** I'v also tried the code below and got this error: `undefined method 'last_page?' for`

```rails
@reservations_completed = user.reservations.where("turned_in = ?", true).where("completed_doc_updated_at <= due_date", true).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per_page(3)
```

```html
<%= link_to_next_page @reservations_completed, 'show_more',  :remote => true, :id => 'show_more_link' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you need to pass a path (the simplest way) as a second parameter to `link_to`, see [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). So for the first case it should be something like this:

```
<%= link_to 'show_more', route_path(page: params[:page].to_i + 1), id: 'show_more_link', remote: true %>
```

where `route_path` is the url_helper for your route.

The second case: try to replace `.per_page(3)` to `.page(3)` as states in the [docs](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari#the-per-scope).